# How to get the last record before the last one in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

How can I get record 34 of a table if the last record is record 35 ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you *know* there are 35 records, you want `limit 1 offset 34`.

If you want to get the 2nd last element from *any* set, you can invert the order of the set and select one element, offset one element. You can implement this yourself by first selecting the first two elements of the inversely ordered set, and then reverse the set and select the first element:

```
select * from
  (select * from my_table order by id desc limit 2) table_alias
order by id limit 1
```

Answer (score 26):

Simplest method

```
SELECT * FROM tab ORDER BY col DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

This will pick one record starting with the 2nd LIMIT 1,1 means skip first and pick next

The order by will have to be done so that last is first
The col mentioned will most probably be id

If you know the number of the record you want however why can't you just select where id=34?

Comment: how can I use this query in yii2?